# minitest-spec-rails went wrong when I make some functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

in my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
end
```

my test file in rail_root/test/functional/publisher_controller_test.rb

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
describe PublisherController do

  describe "GET #signin" do
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      get :signin
      assert_response :success
    end
  end
end
```

my unit test worked fine, but when I run

```
ruby -Itest test\functional\publisher_controller_test.rb"
```

it went wrong , here is the error:

```
test/functional/publisher_controller_test.rb:2:in `<main>': 
    uninitialized constant PublisherController (NameError).
```

I just don't know why it can find my model but can not find the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails expects controller names to be plural, like so:

```
PublishersController
```

Your test is using a singular controller name, `PublisherController`, which doesn't exist. This can be caused by a typo when using generators.

To fix it, change `Publisher` to `Publishers`. Remember to change the filename as well.

Comment: That did not work for me, I still got the error: uninitialized constant PublishersController (NameError).